# PhpStorm 9.0 IDE doesn't recognize package classes

Tags: php, package, composer-php, phpstorm, require

`\Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');`

This is showing up as "Undefined class Braintree Configuration"

And inside of the package `Braintree` it doesn't recognize methods even though they are there in the same class.

Comment: Sorry, but with this little info there will be no any decent answers. Maybe your file is excluded from the project; or it is not recognized as PHP; or something else... Show screenshots .. so that we can see at least some info.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/8f739b9a6fabf1e5c04e38cd4af5a393 it cant even find methods in its own class, havent had this problem before.

Comment: when all else fails (and maybe even before) look in the file menu, there should be an `invalidate caches and restart` ... do do that, especially if this happened out of nowhere. It is a Jetbrains product after all ;)

Comment: @Terraform Well .. IDE does not know what `self::$global` is. Please show screenshots of 1) How that field is defined 2) What type it should be (where it's assigned) 3) Is that your code (I mean -- can you edit that file)?

Comment: It was just an example of that even the vendor/package code doesnt get read properly. Heres what the method is called from in the same class https://gyazo.com/cea7738ac1893797176dd245da826389 , Its Braintree's php libary

Comment: @Terraform Sorry, but 1) that screenshot did not helped at all 2) I do not understand *"just an example of that even the vendor/package code doesnt get read properly"* part. Your screenshot and any info you have provided so far did not give any hints. The best you can do is to create some very simple sample project (should contain all files necessary to reproduce the issue and share it somewhere).

Comment: Did you fix this at all? I also have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I originally saw your question when looking to fix a problem with composer/phpstorm/braintree not knowing where the Braintree classes were.

If you had given a little more context to your question like I did to mine over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40441937/phpstorm-ide-with-composer-not-recognising-package-classes/40442139) then it would of been a little clear to understand what the problem was.

---

### The Problem

Although your problem lies with PhpStorm, the cause has nothing to do with composer nor PhpStorm. But rather with Braintree not explaining that they calling the `class_alias` function at the end of every class to make their documentation easier to read/use at a glance.

You can see this here with the example you gave:

[https://github.com/braintree/braintree_php/blob/master/lib/Braintree/Configuration.php](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_php/blob/master/lib/Braintree/Configuration.php#L551)

```
class_alias('Braintree\Configuration', 'Braintree_Configuration');
```

---

### The Fix

1. The fix that you can do easily is to replace all our alias' with the correct namespace/class. That would be in your file, replacing `Braintree_Configuration` with `Braintree\Configuration`.
2. Or you can wait or PhpStorm to support this (which as LazyOne explained in my question), will be going into the next release of PhpStorm at the end of this month (November 2016). You can view the bug tracker for this bug [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-11936).
3. Download an EAP (PhpStorm's Early Access Program) release to get access to this fix straight away.

Either way you go about fixing this will resolve your issue. Big thanks to LazyOne to explaining this to me for my problem.