# PhpStorm does not recognise class aliases

Tags: php, phpstorm, braintree

I've taken a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37093480/phpstorm-9-0-ide-doesnt-recognize-package-classes), but unfortuently there is no answer.

I'm using PhpStorm and I am building a project with a composer project loaded. I'm trying to make it so that PhpStorm recognises my classes/functions when I ctrl+click on them, specifically, for the projects installed via composer.

I have tried changing the `Source Folders` in `Settings`/`Directories` but I still cannot get this to work.

I am using
`require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` to load my composer dependancies.

**What do I need to do for PhpStorm to recognise my declarations from files loaded through composer?**

---

To support my question, here is some pictures:

My test.php file: (notice how it can't recognise my class):
`project/test.php`
[image]

A project added via composer and installed using autoloader:
`project/vendor/braintree/braintree_php/lib/Braintree/Subscription.php`
[image]

My composer.json file: `project/composer.json`
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well ... technically that package has no `Braintree_Subscription` class defined (I mean -- "proper" definition). Your 2nd screenshot shows definition of `Subscription` class from `\Braintree` namespace.

Here is that file: https://github.com/braintree/braintree_php/blob/master/lib/Braintree/Subscription.php

Notice the very last line -- that "undefined" class is mentioned there when calling `class_alias()` function:

```
class_alias('Braintree\Subscription', 'Braintree_Subscription');
```

It looks like your PhpStorm does not understand such class definition.

---

Here is the ticket from PhpStorm's Issue Tracker: [WI-11936](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-11936) -- accordingly to the ticket it has been fixed on 3rd of November 2016 (2 days ago, basically). The fix (class alias support) will be available in next major version, which is **2016.3**.

You may wait till it will be officially released (approximately end of the month) or try **next** EAP or RC build (watch their [blog](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) or twitter for announcements).

---

Right now (for current and past stable versions: 2016.2 and older) the solution is to use "real" class name (`\Braintree\Subscription`) instead of alias (`Braintree_Subscription`) in your code.

But in any case: using real class in your own fresh code name is the most correct way -- leave class aliases for situation where some legacy/compatibility support is required and other edge cases.

---

**P.S.**
This has nothing to do with Composer -- nothing at all.

It's just the code examples -- for whatever reason (*possibly* legacy/compatibility reasons .. or easier for new to PHP users, do not know) they are using class aliases instead of real class names and PhpStorm does not understand such aliases.

Comment: Definitely legacy, if you check https://github.com/braintree/braintree_php/blob/acd947620ede287b4f3b367435ddfc68a2e44e13/lib/Braintree/Subscription.php you'll see that this file had the legacy file name in v2. The correct usage for v3 would normally be to use the new class name

Comment: Thanks @JimL for clarification. Namespaces in PHP are available since v5.3 (IIRC) and 2.x version of this package supports 5.2 & 5.3. So for current v3 (requires 5.4 PHP) *I think* they should have updated their docs to use current/real class names ...

Comment: Yes you're completely right @LazyOne, it has nothing to do with composer. I didn't really know where the problem was, so I was trying to work it out. Because I haven't really used composer much, I just assumed that is where the problem lay. Looking forward to seeing Phpstorm support `class_alias`! Thanks so much for figuring this out mate